# accessing weblogic plan.xml variables

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I'm trying to add the ability to have multiple instances of one application on one weblogic application. Unfortunately, my application has thus far relied on an environmental property to know where from to retrieve configuration and write some special logs/backups.

The cleanest way to send in a variable to a war seems to be using the plan.xml file -- which is accessible through the console and can be changed on the fly. This way we could have 2 wars on the server, each pointing to a different directory and configuration file.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve this variable. So far I've unsuccessfully tried:

- `System.getProperty("HOME")`
- `System.getenv().get("HOME")`
- `((Context)new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env")).lookup("HOME")`

My plan.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<deployment-plan xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/deployment-plan"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/deployment-plan http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/deployment-plan/1.0/deployment-plan.xsd"
    global-variables="false">
    <application-name>NAME</application-name>
    <variable-definition>
        <variable>
            <name>HOME</name>
            <value>TEST</value>
        </variable>
    </variable-definition>
</deployment-plan>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the `plan.xml` variables are only used inside the `plan.xml` file. You need to put values somewhere else to access them. The simplest way would be the servlet context parameter in `web.xml`. For example:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
 ...
 <context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>inject_value_here</param-value>
  </context-param>
  ...
</web-app>
```

**plan.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<deployment-plan xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/deployment-plan"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/deployment-plan http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/deployment-plan/1.0/deployment-plan.xsd" global-variables="true">
  <application-name>appname</application-name>
  <variable-definition>
    <variable>
      <name>springProfilesActive</name>
      <value>dev</value>
    </variable>
  </variable-definition>
  <module-override>
    <module-name>appname.war</module-name>
    <module-type>war</module-type>
    <module-descriptor external="false">
      <root-element>web-app</root-element>
      <uri>WEB-INF/web.xml</uri>
      <variable-assignment>
         <name>springProfilesActive</name>
         <xpath>/web-app/context-param/[param-name="spring.profiles.active"]/param-value</xpath>
         <origin>planbased</origin>
      </variable-assignment>
    </module-descriptor>
  </module-override>
</deployment-plan>
```

You can access this context parameter with `ServletContext.getInitParameter`.

More information and examples:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13702/config.htm#DEPGD181